# Date based foreach loop

Tags: powershell

$startdate= 07/31/2022 09:00:00AM
$enddatetimestamp= get-date
Read log
Read log after $startdate to $enddate
Finish loop
?? Foreach loop 1000000 times
Paused 60 sec
Write $enddatetimestamp back to text file

My question is how to loop date 100000 times, please. Help me.

Comment: Can you please send me the code?

Comment: Your question in its current form is very hard to process. Can you please use full sentences to describe your issue and give a code sample that can be run by cutting and pasting from your question (try this yourself as well to make sure it actually runs). As it stands, your question is likely to attract votes to close unless you can explain your question more clearly. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for some guidance on how to improve your question…

Comment: I have a .ps1 script, script schedule to run every 15minuts and data will store CSV file , in this script i need to create a text file to hold last timestamp. Means last report line ,last end timestamp. So every 15 minutes i will get new data in this data i need to hold in text file last end timestamp, this is my requirement pls suggest me with example code

Comment: I don't know PowerShell, so that's why,

Comment: Iam stuck in loop , which loop i need to use ,if I use foreach loop how i write a code/script to check every timestamp report and capture last timestamp to add-content into text file

Comment: This link explains how a for-loop works -> https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-for-loop/ and with the command 'start-sleep' you can pause your code to wait x seconds

Comment: 'foreach' is to be used when you have an array of objects you need to work on. if you have a counter (run this 10000 times) you use a 'for'-loop, if you have a certain condition that needs to be fullfiled you can use 'while'- or 'do-while'-loops